# Small queries wait for large queries to resolve MYSQL PHP on Centos 6.5

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql, php, tomcat

I have a Centos 6.5, and I'm running Vaadin on Tomcat,
This application has really heavy queries for reports and stuffs.

My problem is, when I'm connect to MYSQL from PHP, when I made a small query, the queries from the PHP always wait for the heavy queries that request Vaadin on Tomcat.

I try all my best for resolve this.

I think this could be an Apache problem, and I install and configure nginx together with Apache, trying to make the php queries on nginx(with port change of course, on the 81) and leaving separately the Apache for Vaadin.

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 1):

That is how `MySQL` works. DBMS should guarantee so-called "integrity" (ACID-ity) of data so most of operations have lock an access to the specific table(s). Until operation will be completed no other operation should be started at any circumstances. All queries are queued in the line and performed one by one sequentially. Some DB-engines allow to lock not entire table but rather involved rows only, but IRL that is not very helpful.

There are some tricks that help to avoid such lock-ups, but while you are not the one of the Vaadin's developers you can't use them.

Comment: Guys.... I solved this by changing the tables on mysql from MyISAM engine to InnoDB egine, now this thing work flawless.